# Remove the last occurrence of string

Tags: javascript

I have the following string: "\IonSubsystem1\TRAN-88311"

I need to pull off the last word:TRAN-88311 which is an id, in a generic way.

How can I do it?

I have thought maybe found the last occurrence of '\' letter, but it is appear to me that I can't run the following order in JS :

```
var a = "\\IonSubsystem1\TRAN-88311";
a.lastIndexOf('\') ==> error in here.
```

Any other solution is welcome , thanks in advance

Comment: How are the boundaries of the substring you want to remove defined?

Comment: It's extremely irritating how hard it is to get a backslash into a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy.

```js
var a = "\\IonSubsystem1\\TRAN-88311";
a = a.split("\\");
console.log(a[a.length-1]);
```

In your string representation, the `\T` is converted as a tab character.

Comment: what if split \ in string `"\\"`

Comment: @Mahi You can't. That would be not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var a = "\\IonSubsystem1\\TRAN-88311";var b = a.split('\\');console.log(b[b.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex with capturing groups here is a solution.

```js
var a = '\\IonSubsystem1\\TRAN-88311';
var id = a.replace(/(\\.*\\)(.*)/g, '$2');

alert(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to escape that backslash otherwise the apex will be escaped instead (throwing the error)

Wrong

```
x.indexOf('\'); //The first apex opens the string, the slash will prevent the second apex to close it
```

Correct

```
x.indexOf('\\'); //The first apex open the string, the first backslash will escape the second one, and the second apex will correctly close the string
```

Comment: Also check the color of the strings in the answer, you can easily see that the wrong one causes the comment show as text (because the string is never closed) while in the correct one everything acts as expected